# How to use wsclient++ in Android

Tags: java, android, wsdl, ws-client

Please help me! I need create a wsdl - client for my android app. For this i use wsclient++, but i don't know how use it. I have a error

> InventoryServiceAsync cannot be resolved to a type

What i do wrong?

Comment: Async classes are generated only in paid version.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include the wsclient jar in your project.

Also, take a look [here](http://wsclient.neurospeech.com/blog/) at the ***Additional Libraries*** section. You might find that helpful.

Comment: I made everything step by step as there was specified. This not work for me.

Comment: And where is InventoryServiceAsync class?

Answer (score 0):

The *Async classes are generated by the Code generator — when you have use the full version. The demo version does not support Async operations and hence does not generate the class.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I use ksoap2-android